# How to print props object in JSX, i am getting TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to print the value of props in my JSX,even though the logs show the object when i try to print individual objects it throws error TypeError: Cannot read property <'objects'> of undefined

i am using REDUX, i tried looping using map, forEach etc. still i am getting the error. console.log("props.stories") shows the objects but when i try to log individual objects the "props.stories" becomes "undefined"

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

const ShowStory = (props) => {
    console.log(props.stories) // shows objects
    console.log(props.stories._id) // gives error and above log becomes undefined
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>{props.stories.bookTitle}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
    const id = props.match.params.id
    var arr1d = [].concat(...state.stories)
    return {
        stories: arr1d.find(story => story._id == id),
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ShowStory)
```

Comment: {tagName: Array(1), comments: Array(0), language: Array(1), genre: Array(1), _id: "5ce4f468c334fd468bd64578", …}
bookBody: "<p>this is book22</p>"
bookTitle: "book22"
comments: []
genre: ["fantasy"]
language: ["kannada"]
tagName: ["westerns"]
user_id: "5ce261caba9ad5144f1efdc0"
__v: 0
_id: "5ce4f468c334fd468bd64578"
__proto__: Object





This is what i get when i log "props.stories" but when i try to log "props.stories._id" or any individual objects even the props.stories becomes "undefined"

Answer (score 1):

If `stories` is an array of objects, you need to access it using `.map` function like this.

Remove this line to get rid of console error:

```
console.log(props.stories._id) // gives error and above log becomes undefined
```

If you want to print all stories' bookTitle then:

```
<ul>
{props.stories.map((story, index) => (
                <li key={index}>{story.bookTitle}</li>
              ))}
</ul>
```

If you want to print first story's bookTitle then:

```
<div>
  <h1>{props.stories[0].bookTitle}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi hiral, thanks for helping me out . Actually the "state.stories" is a 2D array that's the reason i am converting it to 1D and trying to "find" the record for a particular "id"

Comment: previously i tried to do this 
<
    props.stories.forEach(element => {
        element.find((ele) => {
            if(ele._id == props.match.params.id){
                <h1>{ele.bookTitle}</h1>
            }
        })
    })
>

but not able to use <JSX> inside the "find"

Comment: Not sure if I completely understand your question here. You can't use find inside forEach because find applies to an array. If you want to find story by id then use this:
var story = props.stories.find(story => story._id === props.match.params.id);
<h1>story.bookTitle</h1>